# Retrieve data from firebase resulting in undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was having this problem when trying to pull from firebase. My database structure as such:

I am trying to pull the merchantName and its relevant branches details:

```
function getAllMerchant(){
    var query = firebase.database().ref('merchants');
    return query.once('value').then(data => {
        var result = [];
        data.forEach(snapshot => {
            var merchantData = snapshot.val();
            var merchantName = merchantData.merchantName;
            var branchName = merchantData.branches.branchName;
            var branchAddress = merchantData.branches.branchAddress;
            console.log('check ' + merchantName + ' ' +  branchName + ' ' + branchAddress);
            result.push({merchantName: merchantName, branchName: branchName, branchAddress: branchAddress});
        });
        return result;
    });
    resolve(result);
}
```

However, when I printed out the branchName and branchAddress, I am getting undefined. I managed to print out merchantName though. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: i thinks you need one more `forEach` inside your current one. like `merchantData.branches.forEach()`

Comment: @Hareesh Nope, it told me merchantData.branches.forEach() is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not iterating over the `branches` of the merchant.

```
data.forEach(merchantSnapshot => {
    var merchantData = snapshot.val();
    var merchantName = merchantData.merchantName;
    console.log('check ' + merchantName);
    merchantSnapshot.child("branches").forEach(brancheSnapshot => {
        var branchName = brancheSnapshot.val().branchName;
        var branchAddress = brancheSnapshot.val.branchAddress;
        console.log('   ' + branchName + ' ' + branchAddress);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope that is not the problem. I managed to print out merchantName but not branchName and the address

Comment: Ah, indeed. You're missing a loop over the branches. `merchantData.branches` is the collection of all branches.